# Как правильно управлять зависимостями в deb пакете, который собирается CPack?

Tags: c++, cmake, зависимости

В большом С++ проекте использующем CMake было решено использовать CPack для создания TGZ / DEB пакетов. Бинарь проекта зависит от множества shared библиотек: boost, tbb, pq, grpc... Они линкуются динамически.

Очевидно, что не все системы, которые установят DEB пакет будут иметь нужные версии SOшек.

Для DEB  пакета легко можно установить нужные зависимости в строке типа

```
libboost-filesystem-dev (>= 1.58), libtbb-dev, libc-ares-dev
```

### Проблема 1

В apt лежат старые версии библиотек. Например, проект использует protobuf 3.3.0, а в apt `libprotobuf-dev` самый последний 2.6.1. То же самое с libboost. Например, используется 1.65.0, а в apt последний 1.58.0.

Как лучше поступить? Копировать precompiled SO в DEB пакет?

### Проблема 2:

Для TGZ сборки нельзя указать зависимости явно, как для DEB.

Как лучше поступить? Опять, копировать precompiled SO в TGZ и настроить RPATH для бинаря? Что-то типа `RPATH=../lib`.

### Потенциальные решения:

1. копировать precompiled SO внутрь  пакетов, установить RPATH бинаря на папку с либами.
2. в случае с DEB можно самим сделать .deb пакеты  для каждой зависимости и добавить в свой PPA. Но тогда непонятно что делать с TGZ.
3. билдить всё статически. Но это нежелательно, надеюсь, понятно по каким причинам.

В ответе ожидаю увидеть пояснение как лучше всего управлять такого рода зависимостями для TGZ и DEB, и почему так.

Спасибо.